# Strange behaviour of push_uniq in MongoMapper

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

In Ruby, using MongoMapper, I made the following test:

```
test = (push_uniq @a.id, title: 'test')
puts test.class
puts test.to_s
```

As a result I got:

```
Fixnum
136
```

Why 136 ?

Anyone?

Comment: Not nearly enough context here. What class is this in? What is @a?

test is obviously getting assigned the number 136, so the puts statements reflect that correctly.

We need to know the definition of the class this is in.

Comment: instead od @a it can be 'something', result would be still Fixnum